# Sliding FormsAuthenticationTicket timeout, tieing Session/Cookie experiation to FormsAuthenticationTicket

Tags: asp.net, session, cookies, iis-7, formsauthenticationticket

We're using Forms Authentication as a SSO site.  The site then produces a domain level cookie which will allow access to subdomain sites.

The problem lies in this, if one of our subdomain site has an idle experation of 1 hour we need to kill that cookie, however FormsAuthenticationTicket must remain open for a greater period than the cookie.

So if a user is kicked out of siteA, they still will be Authenticated to SSOsite.  Which means they can still access any links inside of the SSO site and just open a new tab and the browser will let them through.  Is there a way to slide the FormsAuthenticationTicket with the session?

Thanks!

Comment: What a user is supposed to do when he is kicked out of siteA but then goes back to sso site and can't reauthenticate since he IS authenticated?

Comment: Is not form auth cookie the career for form auth ticket. So if one expires, other has too.